# Is there one phrase, expression/ idiom for a social vice of mean/self centered/inconsiderate people who always want everything first for themselves

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

In south asian culture, we would use a roundabout saying as "Window seat" syndrome, that means mean/self centered/inconsiderate people (for spoil brats) always want everything first for themselves (to hell with the others).

What would be an actual version of the above phrase in English language. Usually the saying has come to understand because of school going kids. They engage in this kind of activity involving "my windows seat". Every kid wants to have the windows seat for himself, so they rush to the school bus after they are dispersed from their classes at the end of the school day to have the window seat (the best seat).

Another example which translated in to their adulthood or infects others too would be cutting in line in person or with one's car too. This all displays they having a "Window seat" syndrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common idiomatic expression would be the *me-first attitude* (or *"me first" attitude*).

You can also work with phrases and proverbs that bring across the same idea, like for example *"after me, the deluge"* or *"devil may care"*. Or indeed your own *"to hell with others"*.

Answer (score 1):

Such people are displaying *(a sense of) **entitlement***.

ODO:

> **[entitlement](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/entitlement)**
>   *NOUN* [mass noun]
>
> **1.2** The belief that one is inherently deserving of privileges or special treatment.
>
> ‘no wonder your kids have a sense of entitlement’
>
> [as modifier] ‘this entitlement mentality is completely out of
>   control’